# Unexpected literal in error position of callback in Vue.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, eslint

I'm trying to follow this tutorial: https://developer.okta.com/blog/2017/09/14/lazy-developers-guide-to-auth-with-vue

But are getting:

```
 ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors    
 error  in ./src/auth.js

  ✘  https://google.com/#q=standard%2Fno-callback-literal  Unexpected literal in error position of callback
  src/auth.js:7:15
        if (cb) cb(true)
                 ^
      ✘  https://google.com/#q=standard%2Fno-callback-literal  Unexpected literal in error position of callback
  src/auth.js:14:17
          if (cb) cb(true)
                   ^
      ✘  https://google.com/#q=standard%2Fno-callback-literal  Unexpected literal in error position of callback
  src/auth.js:17:17
          if (cb) cb(false)
                   ^
      ✘  https://google.com/#q=standard%2Fno-callback-literal  Unexpected literal in error position of callback
  src/auth.js:43:7
        cb({
         ^
      ✘  https://google.com/#q=standard%2Fno-callback-literal  Unexpected literal in error position of callback
  src/auth.js:48:7
        cb({ authenticated: false })
         ^
✘ 5 problems (5 errors, 0 warnings)

Errors:
  5  https://google.com/#q=standard%2Fno-callback-literal

 @ ./src/router/index.js 3:0-26
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi ./build/dev-client ./src/main.js

> Listening at http://localhost:8080
```

The code which fails is the following:

```
/* globals localStorage */

export default {
  login (email, pass, cb) {
    cb = arguments[arguments.length - 1]
    if (localStorage.token) {
      if (cb) cb(true)
      this.onChange(true)
      return
    }
    pretendRequest(email, pass, (res) => {
      if (res.authenticated) {
        localStorage.token = res.token
        if (cb) cb(true)
        this.onChange(true)
      } else {
        if (cb) cb(false)
        this.onChange(false)
      }
    })
  },

  getToken () {
    return localStorage.token
  },

  logout (cb) {
    delete localStorage.token
    if (cb) cb()
    this.onChange(false)
  },

  loggedIn () {
    return !!localStorage.token
  },

  onChange () {}
}

function pretendRequest (email, pass, cb) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    if (email === 'joe@example.com' && pass === 'password1') {
      cb({
        authenticated: true,
        token: Math.random().toString(36).substring(7)
      })
    } else {
      cb({ authenticated: false })
    }
  }, 0)
}
```

So in general it's the `if (cb) cb(X)`.

Trying Google the stuff seems `cb(false)` and `cb(true)` aren't allowed, but I'm stuck on how to solve it easily with this example.

This is my login code:

```
  import auth from '../auth'
  export default {
    data () {
      return {
        email: 'joe@example.com',
        pass: '',
        error: false
      }
    },
    methods: {
      login () {
        auth.login(this.email, this.pass, loggedIn => {
          if (!loggedIn) {
            this.error = true
          } else {
            this.$router.replace(this.$route.query.redirect || '/')
          }
        })
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: you didn't defined cb in the second scope, pretendRequest doesn't have a cb parameter

Comment: @afcosta pretendRequest is inside login scope.

Comment: Where are those errors from? Are you using some linter?

Comment: I'm using ESLint, as suggested in the tutorial - so that might be a cause?

Comment: And ESLint preset is "standard".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems like it's caused by some code linting tool you use. It thinks that you need to pass error as the first argument for callbacks. You can get around that by changing the function name from `cb` to something else than cb or callback.

This is how you'd use your login callback with error first:

```
auth.login(this.email, this.pass, (err, loggedIn) => {
  if (err) {
    // Probably do something with the error
    // LoggedIn isn't really necessary, unless it contains some info about the logged in user
    this.error = true
  } else {
    this.$router.replace(this.$route.query.redirect || '/')
  }
})
```

Comment: What if I would like to call `cb` with error first, can you give an example - so I can adjust code?

Comment: You don't have the code that calls `login` in your question, but you'd simply modify that callback function to take error as first argument. Then in your login function you'd call cb(error, value) instead of cb(value)

Comment: Just added `login` call.

Comment: @AlfredBalle Edited the answer

Answer (score 2):

This issue appeared after ESLint approved the [no-callback-literal](https://github.com/standard/standard/issues/623) rule.
There seem to be [many](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/9685) [many](https://github.com/standard/eslint-plugin-standard/issues/12) complains about it.

Currently it matches how errors are handled in Express.JS. For example:

```
callback({foo: 'bar'})
```

I see it being modified in the future, but it in the meantime, you can disable it by changing your *.eslintrc.js* so that the rules look like this:

```
'rules': {
  ...
  'standard/no-callback-literal': 0,
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As per standardJS linting inside callback literals are not allowed. So callback({foo: 'bar'}) can be written as  below :

```
let somedata = {foo: 'bar'}    
callback(somedata)
```

So       `cb({ authenticated: false })`
this can be formatted accordingly.